# Is it possible in Elixir to have code conditionally present depending on Mix environment?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

Basically like `#ifdef`/`#else`/`#endif` in C/C++
I want some code top be present during `mix test` and removed in production, so I don't need to test for `Mix.env == :test` in a piece of code that is very often called.

I know it's considered bad practice, but is it possible and how?

Comment: In which file do you want to add this? How about `if Mix.env == :test do ... end`?

Comment: @Dogbert how about just putting the code into `test/test_helper.exs`? :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: that's what I thought, and all docs say that Mix is not available in production, but my tests for Mix.env work in production in some way.

Comment: How do  you deploy to  prod?

Comment: Using distiilery, but forget about what I said. I set a global config called `env = Mix.env()`, and test that in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While building a release, `Mix` is available. In the release itself, it is not. If you are positive you want the code to be stripped out from the release version, use a macro:

```rb
defmodule StrippedInRelease do
  defmacro fun(do: block) do
    if Mix.env == :test do
      block # AST as by quote do: unquote(block)
    end
  end
end
```

and use it like:

```rb
require StrippedInRelease
StrippedInRelease.fun do
  def yo, do: IO.puts "¡yo!"
end
```

It is to be expanded during *a compilation time* and, hence, everything passed as a block will be defined in the `:test` environment and stripped out in other environments.

Comment: I believe `quote do: unquote(block)` is the same as just `block`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a variant that's worth mentioning - loading env specific code after build - here's one I use to grab an env specific seeds file :

```
# Capture the mix environment at build time
defmacro mix_build_env() do
  Atom.to_string( Mix.env )
end

def seeds_path(repo) do
  mix_env = mix_build_env()
  # IO.puts(:stderr, "env:  #{inspect x} " )
  priv_path_for(repo, mix_env  <>  "_seeds.exs")
end
```